# How to implement rules on a password using statements and loops?

Tags: java

I'm beginner in Java. I have studied variables, statements and loops. While practicing solving problems, I am stuck at one point. The point is, while setting a password of type `String`, how to implement the following rules on a password?

1. The password should never be more than 20 characters.
2. The password should start either with numbers or alphabets.
3. The password should contain only "_", alphabets and numbers.

Comment: You can try to achieve all these rules with one RegExp statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The password should never be more than 20 characters.

Test the string length.  Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the `String` class to find the method you need to use.

> The password should start either with numbers or alphabets.

There is a method in the `String` class that will give you the character at position `i` in a string.  Look for it.

> The password should contain only "_" alphabets and numbers.

The same method can be used to look at the character at any position.  Using a `for` loop.

Or you can use a different kind of `for` loop to iterate the characters in a `String`.

---

I have intentionally linked to the javadoc in the Oracle Java SE (tm) documentation.  Also, I have intentionally NOT linked to the specific methods ... to encourage you to explore the javadocs for yourself.  I recommend you take the time to (at least) read the summary and the method / constructor index for the most commonly used classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read up on [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) matching with regular expressions. Depending on your application, the result could look similar to this:

```java
password.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z][\\w]{0,19}")
```

On a side note, I wouldn’t recommend to use only the rules you have specified to check for good passwords. For example, there is no minimum length check in your rules!

Comment: I think this answer is correct but for someone who just learnt about statements and loops, I think this answer is too complicated

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply God bless you